# how to properly free memory in main that is allocated in a function through pointer passed by reference or by pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-management, pass-by-reference

I'm writing a function to be called by main which allocate memory to a few pointers declared in main. I learnt I can do this by using pointer to pointer or reference to pointer, but I'm having problem deallocating these memories in main. please help me with what is wrong in the following code:

1. using pointer to pointer:

```
void fun1(int **a, double **b, char **c)
{

    *a=new int[20];
    *b=new double[20];
    *c=new char[10];

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        (*a)[i]=i;
        (*b)[i]=sqrt((double)((*a)[i]));
    }
    *c="0123456789";

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *a;
    double *b;
    char *c;

    fun1(&a,&b,&c);
    cout<<"a & b are:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<"\t"<<b[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"c is: "<<c<<endl;

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
    return 0;
}
```

2. using reference to pointer:

```
void fun1(int*& a, double*& b, char*& c)
{

    a=new int[20];
    b=new double[20];
    c=new char[10];

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        a[i]=i;
        b[i]=sqrt((double)a[i]);
    }
    c="0123456789";

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *a;
    double *b;
    char *c;

    fun1(a,b,c);
    cout<<"a & b are:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<"\t"<<b[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"c is: "<<c<<endl;

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
    return 0;
}
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm having problem deallocating these memories" ?

Comment: @Ugo: This sounds like the IT-version of post-traumatic stress syndrome.

Comment: side note: you're misusing std::endl by treating it simply as a newline.

Comment: right, after googling it up I now know endl flushes the buffered stream which was there for efficiency in the first place. so using it in places "\n" is required is an overkill. thanks

Answer (score 8):

This in `fun1()`

```
*c="0123456789";
```

followed by this in `main()`

```
delete[] c;
```

is undefined behavior since you try to `delete[]` a string literal.

Comment: @Brian Roach: Where's off-by-one here?

Comment: `*c=new char[10]; *c="0123456789";` Where does the `\0` go?

Comment: @Brian Roach: The string literal is already null-terminated. It is not deep-copied here, instead the block returned by `new[]` is leaked.

Comment: Oh jesus. I need more coffee. No more SO until I'm awake, thanks.

Comment: @Brian Roach The second assignment is leaking the first 10 allocated bytes and then assigning a pointer to the string literal `"0123456789"` (including the null) to `*c` .

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just figured out there's something wrong with the string by experimenting. Now I know exactly what's wront with that part.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with how you are passing the pointers, and everything to do with how you are initializing the contents of c.  c ends up pointing to memory that was not created by new[] and so cannot be freed by delete[].

Answer (score 1):

```
int *a;
double *b;
char *c;

fun1(a,b,c);
```

You meant:

```
int* a;
double* b;
char* c;

fun1(&a,&b,&c);
```

And then you're ok.

However, as sharptooth says, your `delete[] c` is broken because you just reassigned the pointer to a string literal instead of copying the chars.

---

Please, use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead of all this nonsense:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void fun1(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<double>& b, std::string& c)
{
    a.resize(20);
    b.resize(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = sqrt((double)a[i]);
    }

    c = "0123456789";
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::vector<double> b;
    std::string c;

    fun1(a,b,c);

    std::cout << "a & b are: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << "\t" << b[i] << " \n";

    std::cout << "c is: " << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I haven't learnt std::vector and std::string yet but I guess the char* or string type in C is not the recommended type in C++.

Comment: @string_is_hard: That's right. Messing with pointers and buffers like this leads to errors and bugs.

Comment: I tried assigning "012456789" to string str, then use str.copy(c,10,0); and it works now. Thanks again. Think I'm gonna try learn C++ in a more systematical way rather than messing all the old C stuff along the way.

Comment: @string_is_hard: I think that's a great idea. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "proper" way to do that, your program design is flawed. The very same code module that is allocating the dynamic memory shall be the same one that frees it. So if fun1() is located in fun.c, there should also be another function in fun.c called cleanup() or whatever, which cleans up the mess fun1() made. Otherwise your programs are soon turning into happy-memory-leak-land.

A better design in this case is to let main() allocate the memory, then pass the allocated buffers as parameter to the function.

This concept is known as "private encapsulation" in object-oriented programming.

Comment: I think this is more an exercise in curiosity on the OP's part than an actual design intended for a useful purpose ... or at least I hope that is the case ;)

Comment: Thanks. I know this method is not recommended because the memory allocating and deallocating is in different function making it difficult to maintain. Just trying out stuff. In fact I've had almost all my problems related to char * and string over the past a few days which I thought is some other problem. /flush

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a ticket for disaster. I strongly recommend using stl containers. It is usually recommended to use containers that handle deallocation for you, because deallocation is a frequent cause of annoying bugs. Try to avoid raw pointers, they are very rarely an advantage and make your life more complicated.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun1(vector<int>& a, vector<double>& b, string& c)
{
    size_t size = 20;
    a.resize(size);
    b.resize(size);
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        a.at(i) = i;
        b.at(i) = sqrt(i); // auto conversion to double
    }
    c="0123456789";
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<int> a;
    vector<double> b;
    string c;

    fun1(a,b,c);
    cout<<"a & b are:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        cout<<a.at(i)<<"\t"<<b.at(i)<<endl;
    cout<<"c is: "<<c<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I haven't gone that far in my learning of C++. Still a beginner with old C mindset. But I'll keep your suggestions in mind.